# Антоним для слова «гость»?

Tags: перевод

Как назвать принимающую сторону — человека, организацию — по отношению к её гостю? Слово «хозяин», мне кажется, здесь не подходит. Например, английский язык в этом случае чётко различает два перевода слова «хозяин»: *owner* (владелец чего-то) и *host* (владелец чего-то, принимающий гостей в данный момент). Так вот, есть ли в русском языке, может быть, хорошо забытое слово, которое точно соответствует этой последней роли?

Comment: Упомянутое вами слово хозяин - это, собственно, и есть тот ответ, что вы ищете. Просто в русском это и owner, и host. И антоним тут не совсем точное слово.

Comment: Антоним слова гость - [администратор](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.90.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC.D1.8B). :D

Comment: @shabunc А представьте ситуацию. Вы знакомитесь на улице с человеком и узнаёте, что он приезжий и гостит у кого-то. Если вы спросите: "Кто же ваши хозяева?", то, возможно, человек обидится, не так ли? :-)

Comment: Вы правы, такой вопрос будет неверен. "У кого гостите?" - скажут в таком случае. Не всегда существуют все конструкции. Нет же слова победю, хотя иногда бывает )

Comment: @YellowSky в дополнение к ответу отмечу, что `Администратор` - не совсем верный антоним, т.к. администратор, к примеру, веб сайта может не являться его владельцем, администратор - управляющий, так же и с гостиницей - администратор является лишь тем, кто управляет процессом, но не заведует гостиницей как таковой

Comment: @Vlakarados - Понимаете, при гостеприимстве никому не важно, кто реальный хозяин, главное - кто представляет хозяина. Если это ТВ-передача на Первом, ведь не важно, что владелец его Эрнст, или Газпром, или Путин, главное, что в передаче хозяин - Ургант. ;) Издавна застольем управляет не хозяин, а профессионал этого дела - тамада. Да, все понимают кто тут кто, но ведь хозяин не всегда физически присутствует за столом, и не всегда хочет, чтобы его упоминали. И ведь именно админ, а не владелец, является представителем сайта для его гостей, поэтому я не вижу тут никакого противоречия.

Comment: @YellowSky не могу не согласиться, но антонимом в данном случае, на мой взгляд, было бы слово, которое бы объединяло как администратора, так и хозяина, так и тамаду, почему-то, когда писал ответ думал все время, что вернее всего подойдет `свой` или `свояк`, но это совсем как-то не правильно :)

Comment: @Vlakarados - А почему объединяло бы? Вот в английском же 2 разных слова-антонима, почему бы и в русском двум разным словам не быть? Ведь бывает же у слова 2 разных антонима, например, у "старый" - 1. новый; 2. молодой. А где 2, там может быть и 3, и больше, разве нет? Да ведь на том же и стоит русский язык, что в нём много больше слов на разные случаи, чем в аглицком. ;) Честно сказать, не знаю, куда тут запостить вопрос о том, как на английском сказать "ненаглядная" - "такая, на которую нельзя перестать глядеть", даже определение этого слова на английский не каждый сможет перевести...

Comment: owner - это владелец

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Короткий ответ - у слова `гость` антонима нет.

Если взять в целом - таких слов множество, очень часто эти слова многозначны как в данном случае `гость` может означать посетителя приглашенного к определенному лицу, так и в случае с используемым в интернете словом `гость` - бесправным/не совершившим аутентификации пользователем. У каждого значения слова может быть свой антоним, а так же его может и не быть вовсе.

Итак я приведу 3 известных значения слова гость и возможные антонимы:

1. Бесправный/не аутентифицированный пользователь
2. Приезжая спортивная команда которая играет против родной - `команда - гость`
3. Постороннее лицо, приглашенное присутствовать на собрании, заседании, празднестве, лицо приглашенное остаться на ночлег/беседу в дом/квартиру

Их антонимы:

1. Администратор
2. Хозяин (Команда - хозяин)
3. Хозяин места пребывания

Не смотря на то, что нет прямого антонима слову `гость`, возможно использовать словосочетание `хозяин <места пребывания>`.

P.S.
К комментарию @krokoziabla

> @shabunc А представьте ситуацию. Вы знакомитесь на улице с человеком и
>   узнаёте, что он приезжий и гостит у кого-то. Если вы спросите: "Кто же
>   ваши хозяева?", то, возможно, человек обидится, не так ли? :-) –

Вы спросите "У кого Вы гостите?" или "У кого Вы остаетесь", а в случае, если хотите использовать слово `хозяин` - "Кто хозяин <места> где вы остались/остаетесь"

Comment: Такая ситуация, наверное, объясняется тем, что в русском, например, `we have cookies` -> `у нас есть печеньки`, т.е. указание на обладание печеньками делается таким вот несвойственным европейским языкам способом. Поэтому, думается, последнее предложение вашего ответа - самое оно. Прямого указания на то, кто ваш "хозяин" сделать нельзя.

Comment: Слово "хозяева", по-моему, тоже обязательно должно быть внесено в список антонимов как отдельная статья.

Comment: Хотел добавить, что я как русскоговорящий человек совершенно не обиделся-бы на вопрос «И как вас хозяева встретили?» или «Кто же хозяева?». Заметьте, что в последнем отсутствует слово «ваши», так как это правильней по-русски. Как например перевод «Did you wash *your* face?» будет «Ты умыл лицо?» и никто не скажет «Ты умыл твоё лицо?»

Comment: @Volodya не совсем, "Ты умыл лицо?" сокращено от "Ты умыл *свое* лицо?". Но в целом согласен с первой частью комментария.

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky Никто, кого я знаю, не скажет «Ты умыл своё лицо?» Ну разве что кто-то, кто прожил в англоязычной стране долгое время.

Answer (score 4):

"Хозяин" most often means either master or host. It is rarely used for owner ("владелец"). At best "хозяин" may mean a person who currently uses a thing whether he a legal owner or not (consider "Неожиданно оказалось, что хозяин машины не является ее владельцем").

As such, *хозяин* is the best antonym.

Consider also that *хозяин* and *гость* are cognates derived from the same PIE root ghest- (similarly to *guest* and *host*): for instance, ***ghostis*** meant a person in reciprocal guest-host relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать словосочетание "принимающая сторона", хотя это звучит достаточно официально.